# How to swap to other characters in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

After selecting a character from the main menu, is there anyway to "logout" and play with one of my other characters?

Resetting the game to change the character you're playing with seems like a bit of a chore.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can switch characters fairly easily! Just press Options (or Start on the Xbox One, if that takes you to your inventory screen!), navigate to Settings, and hover over "Log Out."

There, you will see two prompts: **Log Out of Destiny** and **Change Character**. The latter is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I was digging around in the menus but I must've glanced over this.

Comment: It's a really awkward place to have it.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing goes for PS3.

- Open the start Menu (where your character is displayed)
- Go to the **Settings** tab and hove the cursor over **'Log Out'** 
  Two tabs will open, **'Log out of Destiny'** and **'Change Character'**
- Click on 'Change Character'

Comment: What's wrong with this post?

Comment: Your not adding any new information. This is just a reworded duplicate of the accepted answer